# Two-dimensional integral with variable inner limits

Tags: integration, asymptotics, approximation

I'm a physics student trying to solve a scattering problem on the surface of a topological insulator and am currently stuck with integrals of this kind:
$$\int_0^\pi d\phi \int_\phi^\pi d\phi'\,e^{V(\cos\phi'- \cos\phi)}\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}\cos^2\frac{\phi'}{2}.$$
Please note the variable limits of integration over $\phi'$. If they were definite, I would get Bessel functions in the result, but unfortunately it's not the case.

I could make use of the fact that $V\gg1$ and expand the trigonometric functions in the exponent, thus substituting them by polynomials ($\cos\phi\approx 1-\phi^2/2$), but it doesn't make the problem integrable.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how one could integrate/approximate this while still keeping some angle-dependence (i.e., $\phi$- and $\phi'$-dependence) in the exponent.

**Edit:**
Here's my attempt at a saddle point approximation. Since the exponential function is a rapidly varying function, and since $-V(\cos\phi-\cos\phi')\leq 0$ in the region of integration, only the area around where ($\cos\phi-\cos\phi'$) has a minimum will contribute significantly to the integral.
$\cos\phi-\cos\phi'=0$ on the line $\phi=\phi'$, and $\cos\phi-\cos\phi'>0$ in the rest of the region of integration. I therefore expand $\cos\phi'$ around $\phi'=\phi$:
$$\cos\phi'\approx \cos\phi - (\phi'-\phi)\sin\phi-\frac{1}{2}(\phi'-\phi)^2\cos\phi.$$
This gives me
$$\cos\phi-\cos\phi'\approx (\phi'-\phi)\sin\phi+\frac{1}{2}(\phi'-\phi)^2\cos\phi.$$
Notice that the linear term does not disappear, because the line $\phi=\phi'$ doesn't correspond to a minimum, it simply gives the smallest value for ($\cos\phi-\cos\phi'$) in the region of integration.
The integral to lowest order now looks like this:
$$\int_0^\pi d\phi \int_\phi^\pi d\phi'\,e^{-V\sin\phi\,(\phi'- \phi)}\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}\cos^2\frac{\phi'}{2}.$$
**Edit #2:**
The inner integral is now doable, and with the help of Mathematica I obtain
$$I=\int_0^\pi d\phi\,\frac{\tan\frac{\phi}{2}\left ( V^2(1+\cos\phi)-V-\csc^2\phi\left ( e^{V\sin\phi(\phi-\pi)} -1 \right ) \right )}{4V(V^2+\csc^2\phi)}.$$

**Edit #3:**
We can split this up into two parts $I_1+I_2=I$, where
$$I_1=\int_0^\pi d\phi\,\frac{\tan\frac{\phi}{2}\left ( V^2(1+\cos\phi)-V \right )}{4V(V^2+\csc^2\phi)}$$
and
$$I_2=\int_0^\pi d\phi\,\frac{\tan\frac{\phi}{2}\csc^2\phi\left ( 1-e^{V\sin\phi(\phi-\pi)} \right ) }{4V(V^2+\csc^2\phi)}.$$

Here's how the integrands look as a function of $\phi$ (for the case $V=10$):

[image]

Around $\phi=\pi$ the contributions from $I_1$ and $I_2$ nearly cancel out, and since $I_1$ is solvable while $I_2$ isn't, I guess a convenient way to proceed would be to approximate $I$ with $I_1$, only with a changed upper integration limit. Instead of integrating $I_1$ from $0$ to $\pi$, we could only integrate up to the value of $\phi$ at which the integrand of $I_1$ crosses zero. That is,
$$I\approx\int_0^{\arccos(1/V-1)} d\phi\,\frac{\tan\frac{\phi}{2}\left ( V^2(1+\cos\phi)-V \right )}{4V(V^2+\csc^2\phi)}.$$
The result looks pretty horrible though:
$$\frac{\sqrt{V^2+1} (4 V+\log (2 V)-2)-4 (V+1) \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{V}{\sqrt{V^2+1}}\right)}{8 V^2 \sqrt{V^2+1}}+$$
$$\frac{2 (V+1) \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{V+i \tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{V}-1\right)\right)}{\sqrt{V^2+1}}\right)+2 (V+1) \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{V-i \tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{V}-1\right)\right)}{\sqrt{V^2+1}}\right)}{8 V^2 \sqrt{V^2+1}}.$$

Comment: Have you tried a saddle point mehtod? This should help if $V>>1$

Comment: Thanks, I added an edit about the saddle point method, could you please take a look at it?

Comment: But $\phi'$ integration is now solvable right?

Comment: step by step, write down the result and then we see what happens with the outer integral :)

Comment: You're right, the $\phi'$ integration is now solvable (I did it with Mathematica), but what can one do with the resulting outer integral?

Comment: the first two parts in the nominator should be expressible in terms of elementary functions, so we have only take care of part 3. may you like to plot it separately?

Comment: it seems the only relevant contribution from this part is coming from $\phi=\pi$, which more or less just cancels the contribution of the other stuff in this region. We are quite close now ! :)

Comment: Is this what you had in mind ("Edit #3")?

Comment: something like that

Comment: But you may also try to further approximate $I_2$ have to think alittle bit what's the best way

Comment: By the way you could stremline your endresult a little bit, by using the assumption the $V$ is big! 
Nevertheless great work !